# Error while using Arrow library to convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying to convert a spark data frame to pandas data frame by enabling these two flags

```
'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled'
'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled'
```

But I'm getting this error while trying to do so.

```
File /opt/conda/envs/python385/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:108, in PandasConversionMixin.toPandas(self)
    106 # Rename columns to avoid duplicated column names.
    107 tmp_column_names = ['col_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(self.columns))]
--> 108 self_destruct = self.sql_ctx._conf.arrowPySparkSelfDestructEnabled()
    109 batches = self.toDF(*tmp_column_names)._collect_as_arrow(
    110     split_batches=self_destruct)
    111 if len(batches) > 0:

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o1723.arrowPySparkSelfDestructEnabled. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method arrowPySparkSelfDestructEnabled([]) does not exist
```

I have installed `pyarrow` through conda-forge

Did any one faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you insert a type check for `self.sql_ctx._conf` just before the error?  Also, what versions of `pyspark` and `arrow` are you using?

Comment: this is the type - `<class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'>`
pyspark - 3.2.1
pyarrow - 8.0.0

Comment: Can you share sample data? It would be great if we could replicate the problem.